# How do I convert an arbitrary list of strings to a SQL rowset?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple list of strings, which may be of arbitrary length.  I'd like to be able to use this list of strings as I would use a rowset.  The app in question is running against SQL Server.

To be clearer, if I do `SELECT 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'` I get 'foo', 'bar', and 'baz' as fields in a single row.  I'd like to see each one of them as a separate row.

Is there a SQL (or SQLServer-specific) function or technique that I'm missing, or am I going to have to resort to writing a function in an external scripting language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be missing the point.... but;

```
SELECT 'foo'
UNION
SELECT 'bar'
UNION
SELECT 'baz'
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, as a 'technique' there's

```
SELECT 'foo'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'bar'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'baz'
```

(the `ALL`s are to cover the case where some of your strings are the same - `UNION` without `ALL` will remove duplicates); but without knowing more about your situation it's hard to say if this is what you need...

Answer (score 1):

If it's going to be an arbitrary length you could use a PIVOT.  I've only done it a few times before, but it will do what you are asking.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

That may not be the best example, but should help get you started.

Comment: I think UNPIVOT would actually work better for this, but the examples are showing that it's not quite what I'm looking for.  Nevertheless thanks, this may be something I need down the road.

Answer (score 1):

A more reusable solution would be to create a table valued function, as documented [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314824/t-sql-opposite-to-string-concatenation-how-to-split-string-into-multiple-recor)